# Why are sprites still designed with a bounty accept image?

Tags: support, design, sprites

All Stack Exchange sites have sprites to use as images. All of these sprites are also variously sized, so that a certain sprite that is 100px down in one spritesheet may be 200px down in another.

All of these spritesheets have a filled-in checkmark (or other symbol) for accepted answers and an empty checkmark (or other symbol) that allows the asker to accept an answer. Curiously, in all spritesheets (even for *new* SE sites), there is an image in between these two for bounty accepted answers.

Bounty accepted answers, of course, were removed months ago. Leaving this image in for backwards compatibility purposes makes no sense, as

1. the fact that sprites are sized differently for different sites means that a common stylesheet can't be used anyway
2. it's not a placeholder image; it's an actual sprite that is designed to work with the theme.

So why is this sprite included? (Sorry if I sound aggressive, I'm just curious)

Comment: +1 because I almost asked this myself at least two times.

Comment: For reference, sprites.png is at http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png (replacing `stackoverflow` with the target site, of course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm leaving it in there in case we get another type of accepted answer down the road, so I won't have to go back modify sprites.png for every site.

Comment: But let's say a different type of envelope notification was added. Wouldn't you have to go back, design a new sprite, and modify sprites.png for every site? In other words, what makes the accepted answer special? Is it just that it previously existed?